# How to manually render specific component and exclude others within specific route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have `Header` and `Footer` components, which are used for surrounding internal pages.

I also have a `Login` component, which appears when the user is not logged in. This component doesn't implement `Header` or `Footer` components.

The problem is that I can't prevent `Header` and `Footer` components from being rendered with `Login` component. I can't exclude `Login` component to be rendered alone.

I tried `Switch` tag, but didn't get it to work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Login from "./Login";
import manageCategories from "./manageCategories";

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchUser();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div>
                        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                        <Header />
                        <Route exact path="/manage-categories" component={manageCategories} />
                        <Footer />
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a new component that is parallel to the login component to contain the `Header` and `Footer` components.

```
<Route path="/home" component={Layout}/>
<Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
```

and the Layout:

```
    render() {
        return <div>
            <Header />
            <Route exact path={this.props.match.path} component={Home} />
            <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/manageCategories`} component={manageCategories} />
            <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/other`} component={otherComponent} />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: I implemented the `header` and `footer` into `manageCategories` component. Is that right? to do that kind of implementation with each new component?

Comment: you can add a layout component to distribute the nested router components  which need the `header` and `footer` component. The components which needn't the `header` and `footer` can be a parallel router.

Comment: OK, your suggestion is working for layout, but form "                        <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/manage-categories`} component={manageCategories} />
" is not working.

Comment: sorry, `<Route path="/home" component={Layout}/>` I add a excess `exact`, remove it for nested routers.

Comment: OK, the route is working now, but all data rendering inside 'manageCategories' component is not working any more, just blank page.

Comment: You used connect in your original code `connect(null, actions)(App);` maybe  in manageCategories, you also need the `connect` function to transfer the props into.

Comment: And have you ever transfer the props into the component? such as`<Route path="/xxx" render={(props) => <manageCategories {...props}  category={category}/>} />`

Comment: No, I didn't. But when I return `manageCategories` component back to the App.js it works, I don't know why ?!

Comment: Using an action called `fetchCategories`

Comment: There's something wrong, the rendering is not functional properly. all functions stoped !!

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the new `layout` component that should be fixed, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: With redux, if you don't transfer the props from parent components, needn't use the route `render` function. And your manageCategories component's data should have no business of the app component, just use export default `connect(null, actions)(manageCategories)`; and in the `componentDidMount` function call `this.props.fetchGategories()`

Comment: Can you access the `this.props.fetchCategories`  have a console.log ?

Comment: I can only if I return the component back before layout, while for now the component can't output anything to the console.